# Python 3 UDP Multithreading and Multiprocesing

Tags: python, multithreading, network-programming, python-multiprocessing

*What should I change in these files to make make my server process a sequence of requests sent by the one client and also process multiple sequences from multiple clients at the same time?*

**Client.py**

```
from socket import *

server = "adresa"
port = 12000

clientSocket = socket(family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_DGRAM)

message = input("fjali me te vogla:")

clientSocket.sendto(message.encode("ASCII"),(server,port))

modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)

print(modifiedMessage.decode("ASCII"))
```

**Server.py**

```
from socket import *

serverPort = 12000

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))

print("Serveri eshte i gatshem per pranim te te dhenave")

while True:
    message, clientAddress = serverSocket.recvfrom(2048)
    print("Mesazhi i pranuar: " + message.decode("ASCII"))
    modifiedMessage = message.upper()
    serverSocket.sendto(modifiedMessage, clientAddress)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super huge into giving exact answers, and this is kind of a duplicate question. The answer to your question is here: [Python Socket - Multiple Clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003027/python-socket-multiple-clients) and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm